# perl6 functions similar to "car cdr cons" in scheme?

Tags: arrays, raku, cons, cdr

I really love perl6 and scheme. I am wondering if there are functions in perl6 that are similar to the "cons, car, cdr" functions in scheme? What I have been doing feels cumbersome:

```
sub cons($a, $aList) { return flat($a, $aList); } # sometimes flat is undesired;
sub car($aList) { return first($aList); }
sub cdr($aList) { return tail($aList.elems - 1); }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl 6 lists/arrays are not linked list.
However, the `Pair` type can be used to build linked lists, and provides the functionality of those three Lisp functions.

### Using nested `Pair`s

A [`Pair`](https://doc.perl6.org/type/Pair) represents a key-value pair. For example when iterating a [`Hash`](https://doc.perl6.org/type/Hash), you get a sequence of `Pair`s.

If you think of a `Pair` as a cons cell, then you can build a linked lists à la Lisp as a `Pair` that has another `Pair` as its value, which in turn has another `Pair` as its value, and so on.

- The `=>` operator (`Pair` constructor) fulfills the role of **cons**.
- The `.key` method fulfills the role of **car**.
- The `.value` method fulfills the role of **cdr**.

Example:

```
my $l = (1 => (2 => (3 => (4 => (5 => Nil)))));
say $l.key;    # 1
say $l.value;  # 2 => 3 => 4 => 5 => Nil
```

The `=>` operator is right-associative, so that first line can also be written without the parentheses:

```
my $l = 1 => 2 => 3 => 4 => 5 => Nil;
```

If you wanted to declare the Lisp functions under their familiar names, it would look like this:

```
sub cons ($x, $y)  { $x => $y }
sub car  (Pair $y) { $y.key   }
sub cdr  (Pair $y) { $y.value }
```

Note, however, that there are no built-in convenience functions for doing list processing with such `Pair`-based linked lists. So if you wanted to do the equivalent of Scheme's **length** or **append** functions etc., then you'd have to write those functions yourself. All the built-in list processing routines assume normal Perl 6 lists or compatible [`Iterable`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterable.html) types, which `Pair` is not.

### Using normal Perl 6 lists

If you want to use normal Perl 6 lists/arrays as your data structure, but implement the behavior of the Lisp functions for them, I'd write it like this:

```
sub cons ($x, $y) { $x, |$y  }
sub car  (@y)     { @y[0]    }
sub cdr  (@y)     { @y[1..*] }
```

Some comments:

- Instead of using [`flat`](https://doc.perl6.org/routine/flat), I used the [`|` operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_%7C) to slip the elements of `$y` into the outer list.
- The `first` function does not do what you expect in your code. *It is meant for **searching** a list. It interprets the first argument (in your case `$aList`) as a predicate, and the remaining arguments (in your case none) as the list to search, thus in your case it always returns `Nil`.*
  For returning the first element of a list, You can use the [`[ ]` positional subscripting operator](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators.html#postcircumfix_[_]) instead, like I did here.
- The `return` keyword is optional; The result of the last statement of a function is automatically returned.

Comment: "*The last statement of a function is automatically returned.*" How do you return a statement? Do you mean the result of the last expression?

Comment: @KeithThompson: The last statement is treated as an expression, and its value returned. The exception is that when the last statement is a block construct (like a `for` loop), `Nil` is returned if the end of the function is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another set of functions, similar to your originals, and using prefix operators for car / cdr:

```
sub prefix:<car>(List $l) is tighter(&infix:<xx>) { $l.head }
sub prefix:<cdr>(List $l) is tighter(&infix:<xx>) { $l.tail(*-1).list }
sub cons($item, List $l) { ($item, |$l) }
```

These provide an almost lisp-ish syntax, if you wish.

```
my @l = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my $l = |@l;

say "Array";
say "car: ", (car @l).perl;
say "cdr: ", (cdr @l).perl;

say "List";
say "car: ", (car $l).perl;
say "cdr: ", (cdr $l).perl;

say "Literal";
say "car: ", (car (4, 3, 2, 1)).perl;
say "cdr: ", (cdr (4, 3, 2, 1)).perl;

say "cons: ", (cons car $l, cdr $l).perl;
```